# Отсортировать deb пакеты по частоте использования

Tags: ubuntu, debian, ansible, deb

Есть задача минимализировать количество установленных deb пакетов на Ubuntu 9-16.

Как можно вывести список самых минимально используемых программы/пакетов, которые будут вкючмны на удаление в Ansible?

То, что используется сейчас:

`apt-get -y clean autoclean autoremove`

Comment: Эм... в такой ситуации есть смысл поступать скорее наоборот: не ставить лишнего изначально. Потому что "минимальное использование" определить непросто ввиду большого разнообразия содержимого пакетов.

Comment: @D-side Устанавливаемый списком пакетов строго регламентировать, для аудита безопасности требуется снизить количество обновляемых пакетов в системе.

Comment: «регламентировать» или «регламентирован»? если второе, то вопрос не к нам, а к тому, кто вам предоставил этот список регламентированных пакетов.

Comment: у файла может быть (в данном контексте) только два состояния: либо используется, либо нет. наиболее достоверно это можно определить лишь удалив данный файл (или пакет, если он входит в какой-либо пакет) и проверив работоспособность необходимых вам функций.

Comment: Составить список «минимальное количество раз используемых» — практически не возможно [читай можно, но очень дорого]. Можно отсортировать пакеты по времени последнего доступа к файлам из оных или найти все пакеты к файлам которых не было доступа в последнее время. Последнее можно сделать одностроком.